# Creating Object-Oriented Wrappers for the WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, wrapper

This is a bit of an abstract question, so I'll provide the necessary use cases to make this a little more concrete. If code needs to be posted for clarity, just say the word and I'll be sure to do so. I'll write examples for clarity as well.

**Question**

What I'd like to know is whether or not it's possible to create wrappers in C++ for the win32 API? This would be for a simple game engine in particular. The examples posted are merely examples, and not quite questions themselves in the sense that I'm asking them directly, but rather using them as extensions for understanding the main question. Although if anyone wishes to answer these as well, it would be helpful.

**Example One**

I have a simple `WndProc` function which is part of my `App::Game` class which I would like to be able to assign to a `WNDCLASSEX`, yet, because of the fact that it has a namespace and is part of a class, I fear there is no way to do this. At first I thought of overloading, then I realized that the `wc.lpfnWndProc` is part of a struct, and therefore un-overloadable.

**Example Two**

Hiding the `WinMain` underneath the normal C/C++ `main` function, by creating the main function and having it call `WinMain`.

Comment: Hasn't this already been done? To death? Bartosz Milewski has a whole book on that I believe, and there is [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net)...

Comment: I would like to know how to do it myself, though. My goal is to learn, which is why I'm using the most bareboned of apis (i.e. openGL, and win32)

Comment: I'm not sure if understanding and coping with Win32 constitutes "learning". Maybe if you're some monk on an endurance feat...

Comment: I think it does - e.g., it will teach me how to write wrappers...properly, rather than relying on a template library that someone else made. I like to know how things work ;)

Comment: This has been done [many](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), [many](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [many](http://www.fltk.org/), [many](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/), [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) times. They are open source, so you can try taking a look at those to see how it's done. But they are by no means trivial projects.

Comment: Do you want this in C or C++? They are very different languages. A C-based Windows API wrapper will look completely different from a C++ based Windows API wrapper.

Comment: @Insilico I would prefer C++, as I'm trying to make a game engine for a pong game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://vaca.sourceforge.net/